# How to get rid of borders of recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview

The below settings give the left or right border of the `recyclerview` a vertical line.

I also tried to remove all the layout parameter of the `recyclerview`, still it does not work.

I did try to hide all the viewholder and found that the line truly belongs to the `recyclerview`

I am wondering if this line is default, or added by my code and how to get rid of it.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/list_background_color">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fake_space"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the background from the relative layout. I think you'll find that's what's giving you your border.

There's nothing in your RecyclerView as shown that could do it, even if there **is** anything that could do it, and I don't think there is. I think you need an ItemDecoration to get borders into the RecyclerView itself, and you're not showing one of those.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I tried removed all the background of the relativelayout, however, the problem persists.
I do have ItemDecoration in my projects, however, it is added to solely add horizontal spaces between items. So it do not think this is the point...

Comment: I'd still say there is something else causing this. If you've got other pieces of code that apply, it's hard to help without seeing them